How can I preview the review form in OpenReview?
I use OpenReview for a conference and I need to customize the review form.
I understand that I have to go to the Full Venue Configuration page and click on "Review stage":

then provide some JSON to customize the review form, as the default review form doesn't match my need:

After I add that JSON to customize the review form, how can I preview the review form in OpenReview?

OpenReview support sent me the following:

To preview the review form you will need to view it from one of the submissions. If you want to preview the form before reviewers see it, the best way to do that is remove the reviewers as readers of the submissions and then start the review stage so the forms are created for each submission. You can change the start date after checking out the form, and then adding reviewers as readers when you're ready for them to access submissions.

To remove the reviewers as readers of the submissions:

